# Create a Django detail def

Tags: python, django

well these are the codes:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import models

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(models.Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
   <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.urls import path, re_path

path(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

but the result is an TypeError :
detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

and if you add 'pk' argument to detail() like this :

```
def detail(request, pk, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(models.Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

the resualt is another error :
detail() needs an important argument 'question_id'

where is the problem from?

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different names for the same thing: `pk` in your URL and `question_id` in your view function. Django has no way to know they're supposed to be the same thing.

Change the name of the parameter in your route to `question_id` so it matches your view function:

```
path(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Or you could rename the function parameter to `pk` to match your existing URL, but `question_id` is probably a better name since it's more descriptive.